# NSManagedObjectContext how to access _unprocessedInserts field

Tags: ios, core-data

***Is there a way to find if there are unprocessed inserts on a NSManagedObjectContext??***

When using the debugger in *JetBrains AppCode 3.0*  I can browse the field `_unprocessedInserts`

I tried to make a category **NSManagedObjectContext+UnprocessedChanges.m**

```
#import "NSManagedObjectContext+UnprocessedChanges.h"

@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (UnprocessedChanges)

-(int)getUnprocessedChanges {
    return [_unprocessedChanges count];
}
-(int)getUnprocessedDeletes {
    return [_unprocessedDeletes count];
}
-(int)getUnprocessedInserts {
    return [_unprocessedInserts count];
}
@end
```

**NSManagedObjectContext+UnprocessedChanges.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSManagedObjectContext (UnprocessedChanges)
-(int)getUnprocessedChanges;
-(int)getUnprocessedDeletes;
-(int)getUnprocessedInserts;
@end
```

But it won't compile.  Any suggestions how to access this variable[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this seemed to work nicely:  Hello Privates!!

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import "NSManagedObjectContext+UnprocessedChanges.h"


@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (UnprocessedChanges)

//+ (BOOL)accessInstanceVariablesDirectly {
//    return YES;
//}


-(int)getUnprocessedChanges {
    Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([NSManagedObjectContext class], "_unprocessedChanges");
    NSMutableSet* changes = object_getIvar(self , ivar);
    return changes.count;

}
-(int)getUnprocessedDeletes {
    Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([NSManagedObjectContext class], "_unprocessedDeletes");
    NSMutableSet* changes = object_getIvar(self , ivar);
    return changes.count;
}

-(int)getUnprocessedInserts {
    Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([NSManagedObjectContext class], "_unprocessedInserts");
    NSMutableSet* changes = object_getIvar(self , ivar);
    return changes.count;
}
@end
```

Comment: Using undocumented API will get your app rejected from the app store.

Comment: I'm not EVERY submitting my app to the app store.  It is a beta app run through HockeyApp.

Answer (score 0):

`_unprocessedInserts` is a private instance variable within Core Data. It is not part of the public interface to NSManagedObjectContext, which is why your code will not compile.

You should not be attempting to access it at all.

Comment: But i need to know if there are unprocessed inserts waiting... is there no other way?

Comment: `insertedObjects` is a set of objects that have been inserted but not yet saved.